# JNI.h header cannot be found

Tags: java, c++, macos, java-native-interface

I'm trying to create a JNI application between java and c++ and the include #include  is telling me that jni.h cannot be found. I've looked at a half dozen threads and web pages and tried fixes that haven't worked. I don't have anything in the path Library/Framework/JavaVM.framework if that helps, and I can't figure out how to get it.

I'm trying to build a JNI project. I know that jni.h is in the path /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/include but for some reason this makefile isn't working.

EDIT: also, I'm using eclipse if that matters.

```
# Define a variable for classpath
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

# Define a virtual path for .class in the bin directory
vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)

all : hpaprogram.dll

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
hpaprogram.dll : HPAProgram.o
    gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared -o $@ $<

# $@ matches the target, $< matches the first dependancy
HPAProgram.o : HPAProgram.c++ HPAProgram.h
    gcc -I"/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/include" -c $< -o $@

# $* matches the target filename without the extension
HPAProgram.h : HPAProgram.class
    javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*

clean :
    rm HPAProgram.h HPAProgram.o hpaprogram.dll
```

Comment: JNI is at: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\include`.. It's in the include folder of wherever your JDK is installed..

Comment: Not the right 'answer' for Android.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My JavaVM.framework was actually in /System/Library/Framework/JavaVM.framework